# How to return an Iter to 'n' selected objects from a std::map of 'm' objects (c++)

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, stl, std

I am using a `std::map` in C++.

```
typedef map< LONG_32, Dataobject > DataobjectMap;
typedef map< LONG_32, DataObject >::iterator DataObjectMapIterator
```

Now at times while writing various functions for this Map, I would like to return an iter with some specific object which follows certain properties.

for example: I can Iterate through complete map, then i would like to return an iter to the DataObjects which have some specific properties.

Will I have to create a new map with the specific objects ? and then retunr an iter to this new map ?

Edit Addition:
I would like to implement a funtion named:
FindDatawithstate( State A){};
Now this funtion would return DataObejcts which have state 'A', these objects could be more than one so I wish to return an iter to the objects which have the state 'A'.

Comment: What is your goal?  What do you want to do with those specific objects?  If you want a new container full of them, yes, you will have to create a new container.  But if, for example, you only want to invoke some function on each of them, a new container is definitely not needed.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking: (1) We don't know what you are trying to achieve (2) Why would you return an iterator in first place? (3) why don't you return a container with picked data itself?

Comment: Yes, we already know this. What are the use-cases for those iterators/objects on a client side (a side where you are returning them)

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create an intermediate iterator type that gives you a filter/view on iterators to the underlying containers, skipping the unwanted elements.  The code below is a proof-of-concept for this (for production code you might want to think through `const` correctness, disable or pick some semantics for copies of the `Skip_Iter` etc).  It uses a predicate (which can be specified using a lambda when the `Skip_Iter` is constructed) to decide which underlying elements to expose.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

template <typename I>
class Skip_Iter
{
  public:
    typedef decltype(*std::declval<I>()) element_type;
    typedef std::function<bool(element_type&)> Predicate;

    Skip_Iter(I begin, I end, const Predicate& predicate)
      : begin_(begin), end_(end), predicate_(predicate)
    {
        if (begin != end && !predicate(*begin)) ++*this;
    }

    explicit operator bool() const { return begin_ != end_; }

    void operator++()
    { if (begin_ != end_) while (++begin_ != end_ && !predicate_(*begin_)) ; }

    const I& operator->() { return begin_; }

  private:
    I begin_, end_;
    Predicate predicate_;
};

int main()
{
    typedef std::map<int, int> Map;
    Map m { {1, 10}, {2, 20}, {3, 30}, {4, 40}, {5, 50}, {6, 60} };

    for (Skip_Iter<Map::const_iterator> i
             { std::begin(m), std::end(m),
               [](const std::pair<int, int>& p) { return p.first % 3; } };
         i; ++i)
        std::cout << i->first << ' ' << i->second << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
1 10
2 20
4 40
5 50
```

Comment: Hello Thanks. I am at the moment trying the other method. (vector of iterator) would you please have a look at the seg fault ?

Comment: @sumitchouhan: your `OrderMap * order_map;` isn't initialised before being dereferenced.  You should avoid pointers.

Comment: well I will initialize it explicitly, but what about the default constructor of the class ? why should those be avoided ?

Comment: @Heisenberg: default constructor of which class?  If you mean the OrderMap - you shouldn't avoid its default constructor... you should prefer to have an OrderMap object directly on the stack or in a class/struct or container, and not use pointers unless absolutely necessary.  That way you're much less likely to make mistakes.  Really though - your code's painful to look at - can you please try indenting it properly?  E.g. four spaces inside each `{ }` pair?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply return a vector containing the iterators:

```
std::vector<DataObjectMapIterator> FindDataWithState(State A)
{
    std::vector<DataObjectMapIterator> DataWithState;
    for (DataObjectMapIterator it = DataObjectMap.begin(); it != DataObjectMap.end(); ++it)
        if (it->second.HasState(A))
            DataWithState.push_back(it);
    return DataWithState;
}
```

Then you can invoke some function on the objects with state A by iterating through the vector:

```
std::vector<DataObjectMapIterator> DataObjectsWithStateA = FindDataWithState(A);
for (std::vector<DataObjectMapIterator>::iterator it = DataObjectsWithStateA.begin(); it != DataObjectsWithStateA.end(); ++it)
    (*it)->second.SomeFunction();
```

Comment: the would require a second lookup when using them. returning a vector of iterators might be better

Comment: The issue with storing the keys in the vector is that you'd have to `map::at` or `map::operator[]` which would be `O(log n)`. By storing iterators directly you can access the elements in `O(1)`. (Btw I don't see how `for (DataWithState(it)) it->second.SomeFunction();` would even be valid code.)

Comment: 1. The returned vector contains iterators, not pointers. 2. That's the [range-based for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) looping through the vector returned by `FindDataWithState(A)`. `it->second` accesses the `DataObject` in the `pair<LONG_32, DataObject>`.

Comment: @zenith updated the issue, would you please have a look at it ?

Comment: @Heisenberg The only problem I see with it is that you use a pointer when a automatic object seems more appropriate since you're just allocating it in the constructor and deallocating in the destructor. Btw consider asking a new question if your new question is different than your old question. Btw2 modified my answer to get rid of the range-based for. Btw3 when you say "I am running the above code" in your edit, that's not possible since the code has no main function.

Comment: @Heisenberg When you `push_back(it)`, `it` is a `DataObjectMapIterator` (aka `map< LONG_32, DataObject >::iterator`) pointing to an element in the `DataObjectMap` whose value (i.e. a `DataObject`) returned `true` when `HasState(A)` was called on it. It's not a pointer, it's an iterator.

Comment: 1. `DataObjectMapIterator` is not a container. It doesn't contain elements. 2. You can find that out by printing `sizeof(DataObjectMapIterator)`. 3. `it++` will make the iterator point to the next element. Iterator's member functions handle the incrementing. Quite a lot of questions for one question...